# How to create multi daimentional array using each in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to create multi dimensional array each statement in jquery i want below array structure.

```
array(
"1"=>array (
        "1"=>"abc",
                    "2"=>"bcd",
        "3"=>"efd",
      ),
"2"=>array (
        "1"=>"abc",
                    "2"=>"bcd",
        "3"=>"efd",
      )
"3"=>array (
        "1"=>"abc",
                    "2"=>"bcd",
        "3"=>"efd",
      )
"4"=>array (
        "1"=>"abc",
                    "2"=>"bcd",
        "3"=>"efd",
      )



)
```

Comment: show relevant code in OP

Comment: `[["abc", "bcd", "efd"],["abc", "bcd", "efd"]]`

Answer (score 0):

I think... (but im not certain) that you are looking for an object containing several arrays. So you can do this:

```
var arrayObject = {
arrayOne: ["abc", "bcd", "efd"],
arrayTwo: ["abc", "bcd", "efd"],
}
```

then you can access each individual array like so:

```
var firstArray = arrayObject.arrayOne
```

is this what you are after? if not can you please clarify the question.